# Are there integers like $x$, $y$ and $z$ that $6x+9y+15z=107$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have no idea what to do about this question:

> Are there integers like $x$, $y$ and $z$ that
>
> $$6x+9y+15z=107$$

Comment: Hint: $3$ divides the left handed side, which equals the right handed side..

Comment: @Leandro: But $3$ doesn't divide the right handed side.

Comment: So...? conclusion?

Comment: @Gigili: my point exactly. What does that tell us?

Comment: @Leandro: There do not exist such integers, right?

Comment: @Gigili: absolutely.

Comment: @Gigili: you're welcome. :) By the way, it's often a good idea to look at divisors when trying to solve questions like this.

Comment: @Gigili: You can write it yourself! Write down a proof that no solutions exist; people can help you with suggestions (if needed) and you can eventually accept it.

Comment: It may be of some help to check this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity

Comment: @AndreaMori: Great, now I know what is the theorem called. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $3 \mid 6$ and $3 \mid 9$ and $3\mid 15$, $3$ should divide the right hand side but $ 3\nmid 107$. Hence there do not exist such integers $x$, $y$ and $z$ .